# How to typeset a table sideways, yet counterclockwise?

Tags: floats, rotating

I use Latex and have a sideways table, which works OK, but is rotated 90 degrees clockwise from the normal horizontal format, whereas I need it rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise.

I have `\usepackage{graphics}` and `\usepackage{rotating}` installed, but may not be using these correctly.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class do you employ? Which document class options did you set?

Answer (score 4):

You can give the `counterclockwise` option to the `rotating` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
x & x
\end{tabular}
\caption{test}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \usepackage[figuresright]{rotating} also works...